# Nameservers not responding

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, nameserver

I am having an issue trying to get my name servers to respond.  My domain is at GoDaddy and they tell me that everything looks right on their side.  But when I look at intoDNS it says my name servers are not responding.  Any suggestions or helps would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the results from a dig from putty:

```
[root@www ~]# dig @96.47.231.123 www.copierpartsearch.com

; <<>> DiG 9.3.6-P1-RedHat-9.3.6-20.P1.el5_8.6 <<>> @96.47.231.123 www.copierpar tsearch.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: printcmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 33385
;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 2, ADDITIONAL: 2

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.copierpartsearch.com. IN A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.copierpartsearch.com. 86000 IN A 96.47.231.123

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
copierpartsearch.com. 86000 IN NS ns2.copierpartsearch.com.
copierpartsearch.com. 86000 IN NS ns1.copierpartsearch.com.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
ns1.copierpartsearch.com. 86000 IN A 96.47.231.123
ns2.copierpartsearch.com. 86000 IN A 96.47.231.123

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 96.47.231.123#53(96.47.231.123)
;; WHEN: Sun Sep 1 13:32:21 2013
;; MSG SIZE rcvd: 126
```

I've created 2 host names on Godaddy and setup my name servers on GoDaddy as well.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: What in the above output makes you think they're not responding?

Comment: Looks just fine to me.

Comment: IF I try to ping my domain, I get no results.  and IntoDNS shows that my name servers are not responding

Comment: Are you trying to run your own name servers? Or are you trying to use GoDaddy's name servers to resolve your domain?

Answer (score 1):

You ran that on the same host that contains your nameserver, so of course it worked. Running it from anywhere else on the Internet, it fails.

```
;; connection timed out; trying next origin
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

Most likely, you've blocked the ports in the firewall. So you should open TCP and UDP port 53 incoming traffic.

(Also, you only have one nameserver, which isn't good for a variety of reasons, but that's another issue...)

Comment: ok so I opened the ports with iptables.  so do I wait another 24-48 hrs for things to populate?  or should things resolve sooner then that.

Comment: You've still got issues somewhere, because I still get no response from that server.